# Android: Edit developer information in google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application developed and posted on google-playstore. The developer ID on the main screen is as shown in the below image:

[image]

I would like to change the name highlighted in the above image. For Eg. I would like to change `Syed Zakriya` to just `Zakriya`. Is there a way to do this?

**I have gone through the below websites:**

- [Site1](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en)
- [Site2](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en)

  But it does not have any information on how to modify the above.

If anyone can provide any information on this, it shall be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your developer name in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) :

Settings > Account Details > Developer name.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626

Comment: I tried that. After changing i clicked on save, then logged out and then checked on google playstore, the result was still the same :(

Comment: have you waited at least a couple of hours?

Comment: Yes, every edit you are doing on Developer Console need time to propagate. Check back in a couple of hours

Comment: Thank you... Will do that... Will accept the answer once i see the change.